# Find the largest number from multiplication of two adjacent numbers in list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sum

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(l):
for x,y in zip(l,l[1:]):
    c=x*y

print(adjacentElementsProduct([2,5,10,5,2]))
```

how to add method that can print the largest number who came from c=x*y process

example :- my list [2,5,10,5,2]

this code below, well

```
for x,y in zip (l,l[1:]):
c=x*y
```

Compare two adjacent numbers and perform the multiplication process

how to make method to print and save just the largest number form this process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(l):
    for x, y in zip(l,l[1:]):
        yield x*y

print(max(adjacentElementsProduct([2,5,10,5,2])))
# 50
```

This can be written more succinctly without the need to define a function:

```
lst = [2,5,10,5,2]
print(max(x*y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])))
```

**Explanation**

- Indentation is *crucial* in Python. Make sure you indent correctly.
- Your function should `return` or `yield` values. In this case `yield` is appropriate if you call `max` outside the function.

**Vectorised approach**

You can also use `numpy` for this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2,5,10,5,2])

(x[:-1]*x[1:]).max()
# 50
```